# Jsp form submit with list to spring MVC controller

Tags: java, jquery, spring, servlets

I am new to jsp and spring MVC.
I had a jsp which display students list to take attendance with a checkbox in the form.
The Students jsp contains student details from student table and checkbox is from attendance table and my jsp page is like this

### Jsp Code

```
            <tr>
                <th width="80">Student No</th>
                <th width="120">Student Name</th>
                <th width="120">Father Name</th>
                <th width="60">Mobile No</th>
                <th width="60">Present</th>
            </tr>
            <c:if test="${!empty studentsList}">
                <c:forEach items="${studentsList}" var="student">
                    <tr>
                        <td>${student.studentId}</td>
                        <td>${student.studentName}</td>
                        <td>${student.fatherName}</td>
                        <td>${student.mobileNo}</td>
                        <td><form:checkbox path="attendance.presentFlag" /></td>
                </c:forEach>
            </c:if> 

    </table>
    <div align="center">
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Present" style="margin-top: 12px;"/></td>
        </tr>
    </div>
    </form:form>
```

Above jsp will display list of students with a checkbox.
Now I want to submit the modified list in jsp to spring MVC controller to store in database based on the checkbox checked flag, can any one please suggest me how to overcome jsp form submission to spring mvc, I am unable to get what to do. I am able to call a method of controller what I have do for list submission.

Answer (score 0):

Create a button instead of submit and call a java script function and then submit  the form after applying your logic.

Comment: can you please suggest me in detail what should I can do in JavaScript function..?

Answer (score 0):

You need few things inside form tag:

- method="GET/POST"
- action="${request.contextPath}/requestMapping"
- modelAttribute="attendance"

`<form:checkbox path="presentFlag" />` -> will autobind value if attendance object have array of booleans "presentFlag"

Submit name and value determine request parameter with name and value respectively.

Your Spring controller should have request mapping same as in action, as well as request parameter and model attribute "attendance".

https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-checkbox-and-checkboxes-example/

Comment: Thank for your valuable suggestion, I will workout on this and get back to you.